# Find the coefficient of $x^{13}$ in the convolution of two generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, convolution

> Four thiefs have stolen a collection of 13 identical diamonds. After the
>   theft, they decided how to distribute them.
>
> 3 of them have special requests:
>
> 1. One of them doesn't want more than 2 diamonds ($\leq2$).
> 2. The other one only wants a number of diamonds that's a multiple of 3.
> 3. And the other one wants an odd number of diamonds greater or equal than 3.
>
> Find in how many ways they can distribute the diamonds.

My first thought was to use generating functions to find the coefficient of $x^{13}$, for this problem it would be:

$f(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)(1+x+x^2)(1+x^3+x^6+...)(x^3+x^5+x^7+...)=\frac{1}{1-x} \frac{1-x^3}{1-x} \frac{1}{1-x^3}\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}\frac{x^3}{(1-x^2)}$

and that would be equivalent to finding the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}\frac{1}{(1-x^2)}$.

I know that I could use the binomial theorem, but the solution I have says I should be using convolution of these two generating functions, but I have no idea how to use it to find the coefficient of $x^{10}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It   is  convenient to   use the  *coefficient of* operator  $[x^n]$ to  denote   the coefficient  of $x^n$  of  a  series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{13}]\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^2(1-x^2)}}
> &=[x^{10}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1-x^2)}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{10}]\sum_{j=0}^5 x^{2j}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-2}{k}(-x)^k\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^5[x^{10-2j}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+1}{k}x^k\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^5[x^{2j}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)x^k\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^5(2j+1)\tag{5}\\
> &=2\left(\frac{5\cdot6}{2}\right)+6\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=36}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the   rule  $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (2) we do a geometric and a *[binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* series expansion.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^{2j}$ and restrict the upper limit of the outer sum to $5$ since other values do not contribute to $[x^{10}]$. We also use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (4) we change the order of summation $j\to 5-j$ and use $\binom{k+1}{k}=\binom{k+1}{1}=k+1$.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^{2j}$.
- In (6) we apply the formula $\sum_{j=0}^n j=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you!!!! Your answer was so detailed, you helped me so much!

Comment: @parishilton: You're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use generating functions? This problem seems quite simple just using simple logic. It will at least help you verify your answer.

Consider thieves 2 and 3 get allocated their diamonds first, leaving some number $k$ for thieves 0 and 1. Thief 1 has no minimum and thief 0 is easy, so any number of diamonds left over has at least one satisfactory allocation. If $k\ge2$, there are three valid allocations, if $k=1$ there's two, if $k=0$ just one (each depending on whether thief 1 does/can take 0,1 or 2 diamonds.

Thief 2 only wants $t_2=0, 3, 6, 9, 12$ diamonds. Thief 3 only wants $t_3 = 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 ,13$.
The cross of this is tractable while imposing the 13 limit, giving

- $t_2=0$, $t_3 = 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13$
- $t_2=3$, $t_3 = 3, 5, 7, 9$
- $t_2=6$, $t_3 = 3, 5, 7$
- $t_2=9$, $t_3 = 3$

Of these cases, $(t_2,t_3) = (0,13), (6,7)$ have no remaining diamond, and $(t_2,t_3) = (3,9), (9,3)$ have one remaining. The other 10 cases have two or more remaining.

Combining this with the requirements of thieves 0 and 1 gives $10\cdot3 + 2\cdot2+ 2\cdot 1 = 36$ allocations.

Answer (score 0):

It is a laborious work.

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1-x^2)}=-\frac{1}{2}(-2-n)_n(-1+x)^{-3-n}+\frac{1}{4}(-1-n)_n(-1+x)^{-2-n}+\frac{1}{8}(-n)_n(1+x)^{-1-n}-\frac{1}{8}(-n)_n(-1+x)^{-1-n}$$

The bracket symbol is the Pochhammer symbol.

$$f^{(10)}(x)=\frac{d^{10}}{dx^{10}}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1-x^2)}=$$

$$\frac{-7257600(143x^{10}+715x^9+2574x^8+5148x^7+7722x^6+7722x^5+5720x^4+2860x^3+975x^2+195x+18)}{(x+1)^{11}(x-1)^{13}}$$

$$c_{10}=\frac{f^{(10)}(0)}{10!}=36$$

Or collect together all coefficients of $x^{13}$ from your series representation in your question, e.g. by a computer program.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \frac{1}{1-x^2} &= (1-x)^{-2} (1-x^2)^{-1} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{2+i-1}{i} x^i\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x^{2j}
\end{align}$$
Combinations of $(i,j)$ satisfying $i+2j=10$ are $(10,0),(8,1),(6,2),(4,3),(2,4),(0,5)$.

[The above list of combinations was corrected in an edit on  3/10/2019.  It just goes to show that I should not attempt to write an answer just before I rush out the door.  My apologies.]

Can you take it from there?